# Declaring a symbol constant in php

Tags: php, css

I am wondering if its possible to declare a symbol constant in php I want to make use of a * on a form label in several places which must be red and thought the easiest way to do this would be to make use of a global constant and then style it red in CSS. I just want to know how I would go about this. thanks

```
 <td id="form">
 <label for="customer_name">customer Name*:</label>
 </td>
 //i want to be able to style the * only
```

Comment: A "symbol constant"? Did you mean a "string constant"?

Comment: What does a constant have to do with CSS styling?

Comment: On the right hand side of name (or other required inputs), just write 'name is required'. It is a standard practice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Constants in PHP must match this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

Therefore, the only "symbol constant" you could do is `_`

Example code:

```
define('_', 1);
echo(_);
```

Proof: http://codepad.org/1lcDEdMb

Comment: as I'm using the * in the label for id on a form how can i style the * part on so that particular symbol is red?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. What do you mean? You mean you want to replace `*` with an ID that CSS can then turn red?

Comment: Okay. Can you give an example of what a "styled *" would look like?

Comment: its ok fixed in now by using FONT-COLOR BEFORE *